Firewalling Docker Compose
I'm trying to operate Docker Compose containers behind a firewall on Debian 12. I cannot get access to the host machine (set up to be host.docker.local in the containers) to work within the containers when a firewall is up, which is a problem, since my containers need access to PostgreSQL and Redis on the host machine.
I started off using ufw with all the suggestions I could find to make it Docker-friendly, but to no avail. I'm now trying firewalld, but without much more success. On both firewalls, I've tried all sorts of suggestions, including this tutorial that had me add docker0 to the "trusted" zone on firewalld. The change took:
% firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
  public
     interfaces: ens3
  trusted
     interfaces: docker0

But when I start my Docker containers, they fail to be able to access the host. They have no problem accessing the public internet; the issue is only with trying to access host.docker.local. If I disable the firewall, everything starts working again, although that is (obviously) undesirable.
